# Scaling CPU hours based on cores

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, cpu

If it takes 500 CPU hours to run a job with 48 cores, how much time would it take to run it in 20 cores?
If I use the inverse rule, then I find 1200 hours based on the following:

```
500 hours * (48/20) cores = 1200 hours
```

Is it right, assuming a linear scaling (which might not be true)?

Comment: Well, excluding IPC overhead, this is probably correct.

Answer (score 2):

this is correct only for fully parallel jobs however most algorithms have also non parallelizable parts and parts that are parallelizable only up to some finite threads number. For those your computations will be way off ...

When you decreasing the number of cores the error will lead to bigger times than really needed.

In case you increasing number of cores resulting times will be smaller than real ones.

On top of all this there are also sync times. Usually the less cores you have the more often your threads need to sync meaning more sync time is added to the final job time. However this is usually neglected unless your partial-jobs are too numerous in comparison to number of cores or the OS scheduling granularity is too coarse.

There is also the aspect of memory. On the same machine you have the same amount of memory. Once you decrease the number of cores used then they can use more memory for their partial jobs which might speed up some algorithms considerably.

So as you can see in order to estimate more correctly you need to know more about the jobs itself.